# Understanding gradle processResources filter syntax

Tags: gradle, groovy

The following seems like a common idiom in gradle to filter a subset of resource files. I understand what it does but I have trouble deciphering the syntax:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('foo/*.html') {
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [key: 'value'])
    }
}
```

I understand this far:

- processResources is a task of the Java plugin, which is of Copy type.
- I am configuring processResources task by calling the following method:

  `AbstractCopyTask filesMatching(String pattern, Action<? super FileCopyDetails> action)`
- The first argument to the method is a pattern string. I am supplying 'foo/*.html' as pattern.
- The second argument to the method is `Action` interface which has only one method. I am supplying a closure as the implementation of the interface.

This is where I am lost. In the closure body, I am invoking filter method. Where does it come from? It isn't from the implicit project object either. And, the filter method isn't even applied to any file object. How are the tokens replaced? And, `ReplaceTokens` is a class, how does passing a class name as argument works syntactically?

I am not connecting the dots and I am not sure even wether the dots are in gradle or groovy. I have been researching through docs and blogs for a while but not luck. I appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: I am afraid it is only partially helpful. I still don't understand how filter method is operated on a file object without having it as an argument. Of course reading the source code is always an option ..

Comment: What you don't understand?

Comment: And also I feel that I am missing most likely some groovy language features. So, of course 'learn groovy' is also another valid answer.

Comment: It is not run explicitly, this is just a configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142035/discussion-between-hummingv-and-opal).

Comment: You mean that if I had wrote *Learn groovy* I'd have gotten an accept? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` method you're looking for is defined in `CopySpec` interface, exactly [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.java#L345). `filesMatching` is declared in `CopySpec` as well and since `ProcessResources` -> `Copy` -> `AbstractCopyTask` and `AbstractCopyTask` implements `CopySpec` these methods are invoked on a task itself.

The token replacement is done by a [`ReplaceTokens`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/filters/ReplaceTokens.html) class which comes from Ant and when it comes to syntax in groovy `String == String.class`. Filtering itself is run in [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/file/copy/DefaultFileCopyDetails.java) class.

What I may recommend to you is to download gradle sources, import them into IDE and start the *journey* from `ProcessResourcess` class - this is the easiest way to understand what happens under the hood.

Comment: Link to Gradle CopySpec is broken

Comment: It's https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core-api/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.java Now